# laravel get relationship with class model inside model call

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, relationship

Can I do something like this

```
    $mail = EmailInternal::where('id',$id_mail)->with('receiver')->first();

    public function receiver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo($this->model_receiver,'id','receiver_id');
    }
```

Or can I replace the with method so that I can send modelname to function in model

Comment: `->with()` can be an array with a function, like `->with(['receiver' => function ($subQuery) { return $subQuery->where('model_reciver', 'whatever'); }]);`, but that would require `model_receiver` to be a column on the DB table, so it might not work. Did you try [Polymorphic Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)?

Comment: I have a few other ideas, but I'm not sure if it'll work

Comment: If you're trying to make `receiver()` work with different Models, then Polymorphic is the way to go. It would add a `receiver_type` column to your `EmailInternal`'s database table, and you'd be able to target that when querying, or filer return results to that Class, etc. I'm not sure if your other ideas will work either as A) you haven't shared them and B) I cannot read minds 

Comment: Polymorphic is quite new to me so it will take more time to learn, I've only used it a few times and still don't understand much about it. I will try to find a way to make it work so i can better understand how it works. Thank you for the direction suggestion

Comment: Yeah, at first it is a little hard to wrap your head around. But it basically works in that you have a `relationship_id` and `relationship_type`, and `public function relationship() { }` can "morph" to many different models, based on the combination of `_type` and `_id`. It should work with all relationships scopes too, `one-many`, `one-one`, `many-many`, etc. Feel free to [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72324025/edit) later if you need more help. Cheers!

Comment: I just had an idea in my head, I don't even know how to describe it ^^! I'm just curious, how can you use the icon, I'm on a computer and don't know how to use it

Comment: Depends on operating system; to add emojis to this chat, `CMD + SPACE` opens them on Mac, on Windows, it's `WIN + .`, etc. Like this: 

Answer (score 0):

Done!
Change database colunm name and use default morphto